# How to install npm with Karma

Tags: angularjs, node.js, karma-runner

I know there are tutorials for this, but none of them seem to be answering all my questions.

I have both Node and npm installed within my angular project.

Here they are listed in my packages.config

```
  <package id="Node.js" version="0.10.26.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Npm" version="1.4.15.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Npm.js" version="1.3.15.10" targetFramework="net451" />
```

I'm just a bit stuck what to do now... Apparently you should be able to test this by typing '$ node' to see if node is working, but I just get that $ is not recognised. I have been typing this in the packet manager console (I'm not sure if this is even where I'm meant to type it).

Then for karma I get similar errors with $ npm install karma --save-dev that is meant to be the install command. I also tried putting this in cmd but got the same error, and taking off the $ just leaves me with a bunch of warnings and connection errors.

Comment: Have you installed node and npm on your system?

Comment: I just did that now (npm installed with node), but I'm not seeing any changes in results? Where should I be able to type $ node in?

Comment: There should be a Node console. Just do a search. Or you can go to your command prompt and type `node`. I assume you're on Windows?

Comment: Hi, sorry, had to leave yesterday. I have the node console open but if i type $ or npm in then it just says that there is a syntax error ($) or that there is a  reference error and it is not defined (npm). Npm is in my node_modules file.

Comment: Hmm can use npm to get into the help config and stuff, so it's there, but getting ECONNREFUSED when entering things such as 'npm install test-console'. Wonder if this is a firewall problem or something.

Comment: @user3407039 Leave off the dollar sign - that's meant to show you that you type these commands in at the prompt. Open cmd.exe, type the commands in there, and show us exactly what results you get.